# How this nesting for loop works in Python?

Tags: python, loops, nested

I can't understand the second for loop:

```
for k in range(2, n//2 + 1):
    print(n%k, end=" ")
```

How did this formula produce such result?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`range()` has multiple parameters, first is start, second is stop, third is step (which is not present in this example, so the default value is used: `1`).

So your range will generate numbers from 2 to n//2 + 1.

To learn more about range, and for loops:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: Thank u so much now I understand!! Have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

The second for loop prints the reminders of dividing n by all of the numbers from 2 to n/2.

check the documentation of [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

Comment: Thank u so much now I understand!! Have a good day :)